# StartActivityForResult to update a row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, startactivityforresult

I've the following Activity that uses a ListView to display a list of subjects. Each row has a textview which is set to red to indicate the question for that subject has not yet been answered. When the user clicks on a row it should launch an Activity that asks a question on that subject.

I want to launch the Activity by calling startActivityForResult, this will update the row with the fact the question has been asked and turn the textview green.

My question is how to update a particular row in the listview from onActivityResult?

```
public class QuestionListForInTransaction extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;


      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            setContentView(R.layout.questionlistforintxlayout);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            setTitle("Call Question(s)");

            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.txinquestionlist);

            String[] values = new String[] { "Are you the driver?", "Question 2", "Question 3", };


            MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);




          }//end of onCreate




          public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
              private final Context context;
              private final String[] values;

              public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
                super(context, R.layout.questionlisttxinrowlayout, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
              }

              @Override
              public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionlisttxinrowlayout, parent, false);

                TextView question = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestionforintx);
                question.setText(values[position]);

                TextView answered = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatusbox);
                answered.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                String questionStr = values[position];
                rowView.setTag(questionStr);


                return rowView;

              }




            } //end of adapter class



          OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Toast.makeText(QuestionListForInTransaction.this, "pos = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String question = (String)view.getTag();

                if(question.equalsIgnoreCase("Are you the driver?")){

                     //Toast.makeText(QuestionListForInTransaction.this, "Are you the driver?" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    final int QUESTION_REQUEST = 1;
                    Intent questionIntent = new Intent(QuestionListForInTransaction.this, Question.class);
                    startActivityForResult(questionIntent, QUESTION_REQUEST);

                     //TextView answered = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowstatusbox);
                     //answered.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                }


            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null)
            int result = extras.getInt("result");

            //*********************update a row green**********************
        }

    } //end of class
```

Comment: You can create custom class and have two values String and boolean and set the boolean false when you get the result. Then notify adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Create some custom wrapper class like this:

```
public class QuestionWrapper {
private String mQuestionText;
private boolean mIsAsked;

public QuestionWrapper(String defaultQuestionText, boolean isAsked) {
    mQuestionText = defaultQuestionText;
    mIsAsked = isAsked;
}

public boolean isAsked() {
    return mIsAsked;
}

public void setIsAswked(boolean isAsked) {
    mIsAsked = isAsked;
}

public String getQuestionText() {
    return mQuestionText;
}
```

}

then you need to set List of this wrappers to Adapter:

```
public class QuestionListForInTransaction extends ActionBarActivity {
    List<QuestionWrapper>  mWrappers = new ArrayList<>();
    MySimpleArrayAdapter mAdapter;
```

....

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    ....
    wrappers.add(new QuestionWrapper("Are you the driver?",false));
    wrappers.add(new QuestionWrapper("Question 2",false));
    wrappers.add(new QuestionWrapper("Question 3",false));

    mAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, wrappers);
    ....
```

and Update Your Adapter like this:

```
    public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuestionWrapper> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<QuestionWrapper> mWrappers;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionWrapper> wrappers) {
        super(context, R.layout.questionlisttxinrowlayout, wrappers);
        this.context = context;
        this.mWrappers = wrappers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionlisttxinrowlayout, parent, false);
        QuestionWrapper wrapper = mWrappers.get(position);
        TextView question = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestionforintx);
        question.setText(wrapper.getQuestionText());

        TextView answered = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatusbox);
        if (wrapper.isAsked()) {
            answered.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            answered.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

        rowView.setTag(wrapper.getQuestionText());

        return rowView;

    }
```

onActivityResult - Need to update your wrapper class and adpater:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
   ....
   mWrappersList.get(yourPosition).setAsked(true/false);
   if (mAdapter!=null){
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ...
}
```

I think for RequestCode in startActivityForResult you can use Adapter click position.

Comment: hey thanks for taking the time to do this, appreciated! i'm getting 1 error however, "Cannot refer to an instance field mWrappers while explicitly invoking a constructor" this is for the mWrappers variable in the super part of the adapter constuctor.

Comment: i just renamed the mWapper in the outter class. Thanks alot for your help :)